# Coordinate system used in QGIS's Advanced Digitizing tools and how can it be changed

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to draw a point at a specific location (set of coordinates) for a map. I have read other answers and QGIS documentation on how to use the Advance Digitizing tools / panel and figure I understand enough to be able to do this.

However, I cannot enter the coordinates into the X and Y boxes as instructed. The default coordinate display for the advanced digitizing tool panel is different to the coordinates I have (both easting and northings, and decimal coordinates). I believe the advanced digitizing tool panel is by default set to map units (meters). The coordinates appearing in the X and Y boxes as I move the cursor around the screen are 5 and 7 digits long whereas the decimal coordinates for the point location and only 2 and 3 digits long (decimal coordinates begin with 34 and 142, also see screenshot below).

[image: Advanced Digitizing panel verses coordinate box]

I cannot convert my coordinates to match the default display as I am not certain what unit this is, and I suspect it is something like meters east and north of a specific point.

Coordinate system: Projected GDA94 / MGA zone 54 (this is in Australia)
Measurements: GRS 1980 (EPSG: 7019)

Answer (score 2):

It will follow your Project CRS which is shown at the bottom right of QGIS window:

[image]

Just click on the CRS (the globe) and change it to whatever you need it to be changed, let's say WGS84:

[image]

[image]

The values have now changed to the project CRS:

[image]

If your coordinates in the status bar is displayed in Degree Minutes Seconds and you would like to have it displayed in Decimal degree go to > Project Properties / General / Coordinate and Bearing display then Coordinate formats (customize ... button).

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is inappropriate about the Coordinate reference system I have chosen. The coordinate box at the bottom of the screen displays as degrees minutes and seconds. The problem is that the coordinates displaying in the X and Y boxes in the Advanced Digitizing panel are an entirely different set of numbers, and I do not understand how the two relate.

Comment: I cannot find EPSG:7019 in my QGIS installation which is weird. Is it a custom CRS that you have added? As for your other question about the Deg Min Sec, please refer to my update.

Comment: EPSG:7019 is the default CRS for ellipsoid measurements set for the project. I am using QGIS 3.28.

Comment: GRS 1980 EPSG:7019 is the ellipsoid for GDA94 / MGA zone 54.